# How pass value of a derived string to v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to pass a value to v-model using a method but its not working.

I have included radio selectors at the top which toggle the value of a data variable **'field'** from **name** to **place** and viz-a-viz.

v-model of the text input contains **field** which I want to update using changeField() method.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
 data: {
  name:'',
  place:'',
  field:'',
  selectedField:'name',
 },
 methods:{
  changeField(){
   if(this.selectedField=='name'){
    this.field='name';
   }
   else{
    this.field='place';
   }
  }
 },
})
```

```css
body {padding: 15px;}
input {
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding:5px ;
 border:thin solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

 <input type='radio' v-model='selectedField' value='name' @change='changeField'>Name
 <input type='radio' v-model='selectedField' value='place'@change='changeField'>Place

<br>
 <input type="text" v-model="field">
 <br><br>
 {{selectedField}}

 <br>
  Field name: {{field}}
  <br>
  Name: {{name}} 
  <br>
  Place: {{place}}
</div>
```

Based on the radio selection, I want to show the output in front of name / place at the bottom. I want to do this only using single text input. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You can't do this with a single input. Use two inputs and manage their visibility using `v-if`.

Comment: Your example above is working fine.

Comment: @Frank: thanks for the response, I am able to do that using v-if but just posted on stackoverflow to see if someone can help do the same using single input.

Comment: @santanubera: I want to show the data from text input in {{name}} if I select 'Name' in radio button and the same in {{place}} if I select 'Place' in radio input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **watch** property to watch for value changes. Whenever you type something in the textbox the value of the **field** property changes and it calls the watcher. According to the value of **selectedField** property, the corresponding property gets the value. So if **selectedField** is **place** then the value goes to the property **place**. Here is the example -

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    name:'',
    place:'',
    field:'',
    selectedField:'name',
  },
  watch:{
    field:function(value){
      if(this.selectedField == 'name')
        this.name = value;
      else
        this.place = value;
    }
  },
  methods:{
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Did it using [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
    data: {
        name:'',
        place:'',
        field:'',
        selectedField:'name',
    },
    watch: {
        field() {
            if (this.selectedField=='name'){
                this.name=this.field;
            } else {
                this.place=this.field
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        changeField(){
            if(this.selectedField=='name'){
                this.field='name';
            }
            else{
                this.field='place';
            }
        }
    },
})
```

```css
body {padding: 15px;}
input {
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding:5px ;
    border:thin solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

    <input type='radio' v-model='selectedField' value='name' @change='changeField'>Name
    <input type='radio' v-model='selectedField' value='place'@change='changeField'>Place

<br>
    <input type="text" v-model="field">
    <br><br>
    {{selectedField}}

    <br>
        Field name: {{field}}
        <br>
        Name: {{name}}  
        <br>
        Place: {{place}}
</div>
```